# How to make it so a list is chosen and then an image will be drawn in that location?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have these 4 lists:

```
attempt_01 = [['Piece A', 'In box']] 
attempt_02 = [['Piece B', 'In box']] 
attempt_03 = [['Piece C', 'In box']] 
attempt_04 = [['Piece D', 'In box']]
```

and I need to create a function being

```
def attempt(attempt_number):
```

so that images that I have created go to these points and start drawing.

So let's say `attempt_01` has been chosen then only the first piece of my image will be drawn.
Due to the large amount of code that has been written I cannot post my image that has been drawn using turtle.

I have tried this code below so that when the first attempt is put in the function, only A will be drawn, but I do not know how to get only A to draw.

```
def draw_attempt(attempt_number):
    if 'Piece A' and 'In box':
        x = 0, 350
    elif 'Piece B' and 'In box':
        y = 0, 350
    elif 'Piece C' and 'In box':
        z = 0, 350
    elif 'Piece D' and 'In box':
        p = 0, 350
    goto(x)
    #STARTS DRAWING FOR IMAGE A(PIECE A CODE IS HERE)
    goto(y)
    #STARTS DRAWING FOR IMAGE A(PIECE B CODE IS HERE)
    goto(z)
    #STARTS DRAWING FOR IMAGE A(PIECE C CODE IS HERE)
    goto(p)
    #STARTS DRAWING FOR IMAGE A(PIECE D CODE IS HERE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need something like this:

```
def draw_attempt(attempt_number):
    if 'In box':
        x = 0, 350
    elif 'Top_Right':
        x = 350, 350
    elif 'Bottom_Left':
        x = -350, -350
    goto(x)

    if 'Piece A':
        #STARTS DRAWING FOR IMAGE A(PIECE A CODE IS HERE)
    elif 'Piece B':
        #STARTS DRAWING FOR IMAGE B(PIECE B CODE IS HERE)
    elif 'Piece C':
        #STARTS DRAWING FOR IMAGE C(PIECE C CODE IS HERE)
```

Comment: thanks but what happens if there was more attempts say attempt_5= [['Piece A', 'Top_Right']]. Is there an easier way to do it for different locations. say attempt_6=[['Piece A', 'Top_Left']]. using top left coords are -350,350 and top right coords 350,350 ?

Comment: Do you have absolutely the same blocks of code for drawing? (I am talking about blocks `#STARTS DRAWING FOR IMAGE A(PIECE D CODE IS HERE)`) If yes, I'll simplify the code.

Comment: Also if attempt_7 = [['Piece D', 'Bottom left'], ['Piece B', 'In box'],
              ['Piece C', 'Bottom right'], ['Piece A', 'Top right']] , how do u go about getting the pieces in that order?

Comment: Yes same drawing codes, like they can be drawn from any position

Comment: Oh wait my bad they are different drawing blocks sorry.

Comment: i understand this part now thanks but what happens say if i have an attempt such as attempt_7 = [['Piece D', 'Bottom left'], ['Piece B', 'In box'], ['Piece C', 'Bottom right'], ['Piece A', 'Top right']] where each piece is drawn in a different order in a different position?

Comment: To support more positions and more images you can just extend both `if` blocks. In the code above you can see only three positions and three images, but you can add as many items as you need.

Comment: ok thankyou so much but what about the order? say if piece d has to be drawn first?

Comment: In this case you need to inform the code about the expected order. You can put "piece D" in the very beginning of the list of drawing elements.

Comment: ok but say theres other attempts in different orders so is that the only way to rearrange each time?

Comment: There are many ways to rearrange something. I don't understand your question. Could you add more details? Or may be create one more question on Stackoverflow?